# BackgroundTask in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task

I've a problem with registration of two different backgroundtask (different name and different entry point) on uwp.

I use this code at starting :

```
var registration = BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.FirstOrDefault(reg => reg.Value?.Name == taskName).Value as BackgroundTaskRegistration;

if (registration == null)
{
    var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

    if (taskName != null)
    {
        builder.Name = taskName;
    }
    builder.TaskEntryPoint = entryPoint;
    builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
    registration = builder.Register();
}
```

TaskName is different between two called
On second called, i've an exception on registration :

> "Not enough quota is available to process this command"

What's this error?

Thanks

Comment: What are the OS version and TargetPlatformVersion you are using? The code you've posted is right. While testing in my side, it works well. Have you tried in any other machine?  Do you get the same error?

Comment: I'm on windows 10 Pro (Build 15.11 and version 10.0.10586.494).
I found solution, i must put Task.Delay(5000) between unregister and new register. It's not clean but it's the only solution i founded for moment.